# building kernel-debug rpm from linux kernel's source fails at cannot find debugfiles.list, no such file or directory

Tags: linux-kernel

I want to build `kernel-debuginfo* rpm` from linux's kernel source code.

So I changed the `scripts/package/mkspec` to remove the '`echo "%define debug_package %{nil}"`' line.

But after compiling with `make rpm`, i would get the error message:

> Could not open %files file ...... debugsources.list: No such file or
>   directory

P.S: The source-code linux kernel's version is 3.10, and my host's version is centos7。

How can I fix the problem？Or how can I build the `kernel-debuginfo*.rpm` in another way?

Answer (score 0):

This is because

> echo "%define __spec_install_post /usr/lib/rpm/brp-compress || :"
>   echo "%define debug_package %{nil}"

line above is not terminating properly. 
try editing line as

`echo "%define __spec_install_post /usr/lib/rpm/brp-compress "`

Answer (score 0):

you need to changed the scripts/package/mkspec to run find-debuginfo.sh in %install

```
%install
... ...(your code)
/usr/lib/rpm/find-debuginfo.sh %{_builddir}/%{?buildsubdir}
```